# What miss, with connect Firestore and ListView for random results in sample?

Tags: java, android, firebase, listview, google-cloud-firestore

I try to connect my `Firestore` to `ListView`. With my `Query` there are put 20 records and 3 random of it, put in `ArrayList`(`randomPlaceList`), then I logical try to include this `ArrayList` to my custom `adapter`. But I miss something..

EDITED with some change variables; Now I have this error:

> Process: com.example.arara.myapplication, PID: 10283
>       java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 0
>           at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
>           at com.example.arara.myapplication.MainActivity$1.onComplete(MainActivity.java:46)

In this line:

```
Peoples item = randomPlaceList.get(randomIndex);
```

ListViewPlaces class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference placeRef = rootRef.collection("peoples");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    placeRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                List<Peoples> peoplesList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    Peoples peoples = document.toObject(Peoples.class);
                    System.out.println(peoples);
                    peoplesList.add(peoples);
                }
                if (peoplesList.size() > 0) {
                    System.out.println(peoplesList);
                    int placeCount = peoplesList.size();
                    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
                    List<Peoples> randomPlaceList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                        int randomIndex = randomGenerator.nextInt(placeCount);;
                        Peoples item = randomPlaceList.get(randomIndex);
                        randomPlaceList.add(item);
                    }
                    ListView mListView = findViewById(R.id.place_list);
                    PeoplesAdapter peoplesAdapter = new PeoplesAdapter(getBaseContext(), randomPlaceList);
                    mListView.setAdapter(peoplesAdapter);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

}
```

Adapter class:

```
public class PeoplesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Peoples> {
public PeoplesAdapter(Context context, List<Peoples> list) {
    super(context, 0, list);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View listItemView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    if (listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
    }
    Peoples peoples = getItem(position);
    Log.d("TAG", peoples.getName());
    String name = peoples.getName();
    ((TextView) listItemView).setText(name);

    return listItemView;
}
}
```

And Model class:

```
class Peoples {
private String name, age;

public Peoples() {}

public Peoples(String name, String age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getAge() {
    return age;
}
}
```

Firestore database:

[image]

Comment: What is the behaviour you excepted/what does happen? Is there just nothing? In that case, you should check whether `l_check1` really returns `true`

Comment: I'm edited question@Hanno Gödecke In previous activity, I `putExtra` status of `checkbox`, with it all good. Depending on which status I put, I take the `query` to Firebase. The problem in connect Adapter with ListView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can display data from a Cloud Firestore into a "ListView" using a custom "ArrayAdapter" on Android.

First of all, to add data to the database, you should use the following lines of code:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference placesRef = rootRef.collection("places");
Places places = new Places("PlaceOne", "ImageOne");
placesRef.document().set(places);
```

In this way, you can add as many places as you want. So, you'll have a database structure that will look like this:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- places (collection)
         |
         --- placeIdOne (document)
         |      |
         |      --- image: "ImageOne"
         |      |
         |      --- name: "NameOne"
         |
         --- placeIdTwo (document)
         |      |
         |      --- image: "ImageTwo"
         |      |
         |      --- name: "NameTwo"
         |
         --- //And so on
```

To be more clear, please see the image below:

[image]

If you want to query the data, you need to use a `Query` object.

```
Query query = placesRef.whereEqualTo("name", "NameOne");
```

But because I only have a few records in the database, I will use only the `placesRef` CollectionReference.

Assuming you already have a "ListView" in your .XML file that looks like this:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/place_list"/>
```

To display the data, first you need to create an adapter class. This class should look like this:

```
public class PlacesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Places> {
    public PlacesAdapter(Context context, List<Places> list) {
        super(context, 0, list);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View listItemView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
        }

        Places places = getItem(position);

        String name = places.getName();
        ((TextView) listItemView).setText(name);

        return listItemView;
    }
}
```

Then in your `onCreate()` method use the following code:

```
ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.place_list);
PlacesAdapter placesAdapter = new PlacesAdapter(getApplicationContext(), randomPlaceList);
mListView.setAdapter(placesAdapter);
```

And right after that, get the data and notify the adapter about the changes:

```
placesRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            List<Places> placesList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                Places places = document.toObject(Places.class);
                placesList.add(places);
            }

            int placeCount = placesList.size();
            Random randomGenerator = new Random();
            List<Places> randomPlaceList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
                randomPlaceList.add(placesList.get(randomGenerator.nextInt(placeCount)));
            }
            placesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
});
```

The result in your ListView will be, 3 random places each time you start your app.

[image]

Comment: I know that @Alex Mamo, I did like that, but in the bottom of `onComlete` method, where I create `mListAdapter`, I have an error in constructor of ArrayAdapter, in round brackets(`this, randomPlaceList`). Constructor with Context, can't be applied to costructor with `QuerySnapshoot`

Comment: I ask for your help within 5 days, could you spend 5 minutes in those 5 days and write me an answer?

Comment: Generally speaking , here on stackoverflow.com, nobody will do your homework/project for you. As you can see, you tried 3 times to add the same questions but no one has answered, besides me. Note that this site is incredibly inefficient when it comes to interactive debugging. But, I will write this time the code for you.

Comment: I understand you, and I'm not child, I uderstand where am I, and what you can just leave and ignore my request. But you only person, who help me and not the first time. And I very grateful for that to you. I just start this way, and my first project is very important to me, and this problem is the last, that I can't decide on my own. Anyway, it's not your problems, but this time I'm still counting on you.

Comment: Ok, I'll you write the code right now and I'll leave a comment when I'm done.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Mamo, just last time, help me to change working RecycleView on working ListView with my 3 random records, and how to apply your method to 13500 my queries, other that option that I know, just add to each request. It's not hard, but I'm afraid that code will be more than 64bit and will not compile. And I never again will shift my problems to you..

Comment: Just checked, everything is fine@Alex Mamo Thank you so much!!!!! One problem was, that all items in `ListView` was white, but I change in `onCreate` method `getApplicationContext` to `getBaseContext`, and it helped. Just want to say, if I apply this `.addOnCompleteListener` to object `query`, without any conditions, and then out of `OnCreate` or in, I use my `if` loop with checking conditions of 500 different `queries`, if this method apply to each of them?

Comment: Thank you again @Alex Mamo. You realy save me and gave me new inspiration!

Comment: Cheers! @SpikeJohnson

Comment: Hi @Alex Mamo, it's me again. Already was fine with my project, but today I run it and get this error: Process: com.example.eugene.lafinalproduction, PID: 9741 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: 0 at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:182) at com.example.eugene.lafinalproduction.ListViewPlaces$1.onComplete(ListViewPlaces.java:63) in this row: randomPlaceList.add(placesList.get(randomGenerator.nextInt(placeCount))); what is that? in morning today all was fine, I just restart pc, and this disaster came

Comment: Please post another fresh question with all details, so me and other users can help you.

Comment: Got it! @Alex Mamo

Comment: Ok, got it! Must to change: Peoples item = randomPlaceList.get(randomIndex); on this: Peoples item = peoplesList.get(randomIndex); But later, when you helped me @Alex Mamo, all was good too, just some unbelievable reasons, the error coming. Just a magic for me!