# add entry to ListView from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-listview

Good morning,

I am trying to get data from the Firestore and add those to my Listview. Unfortunately, it doesn't work and I am not sure why. The code runs but doesn't add any entries to my Listview. My code looks as following:

```
    public void createListViewcontent() {

        listView = findViewById(R.id.mylistview);
        final ArrayList<String> Listviewcontent= new ArrayList<String>();
        db.collection("ok")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {               

                            Listviewcontent.add(document.getId());
                            Toast.makeText(kk.this, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Toast.makeText(kk.this, "weird", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(kk.this, "failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });


        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Listviewcontent);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Best regards
androidbeginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the results from the database, you are adding them to the list, but you do **not** notify the adapter. That's the whole idea, you get the items and inform the adapter right after that. So should simply add the following line of code:

```
arrayAdapter.notifydatasetchanged();
```

Right after the for loop ends:

```
db.collection("ok")
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {

                        Listviewcontent.add(document.getId());
                        Toast.makeText(kk.this, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Toast.makeText(kk.this, "weird", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    arrayAdapter.notifydatasetchanged(); //Notify the adapter
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(kk.this, "failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

You can see a working example in my answer from the following post:

- [What miss, with connect Firestore and ListView for random results in sample?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50223779/what-miss-with-connect-firestore-and-listview-for-random-results-in-sample/50228240)