# how to get all names of users having userId as their phone number and store it in a listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, google-cloud-firestore, collections

I have collection of "users" and their document is stored as their phone number in Firebase Firestore.
when I click the phone number it shows the users details.

Now I want to get all names of all users and store the name list in a listview. for example 10 users are there and user id is their phone number and they have name , password , email stored . so I want 10 users names only to be shown in a list view
I dont know how to execute the query. please help me with this. the following code shows every values of one user only but I want only names of every users

```
public class solo_m1_participants extends Fragment {

    private ListView listView;
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_solo_m1_participants, container, false);

        listView = view.findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        db.collection("users")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult())) {

                            String value = document.getData()+"\n";
                            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),
                                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Collections.singletonList(value));
                            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                            Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                    }
                });

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: please I would love to get the answer of this problem .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have made a small problem otherwise everything is ok

```
private ListView listView;
private final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

ArrayList<String> userName =  new ArrayList<>();
@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_solo_m1_participants, container, false);

            listView = view.findViewById(R.id.list_view);

            db.collection("users")
                    .get()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            userName.clear();
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult())) {
                                userName.add(document.getString("Name"));
                            }
                            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),
                                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, userName);
                            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        } else {
                            userName.clear();
                            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),
                                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, userName);
                            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        }
                    });

            return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code lies in the fact that you are creating a new instance of your ArrayAdapter class, at every iteration of the for-loop, meaning that you'll end up having only a single user displayed, rather than all users. The key to solving this issue is to create an adapter with an empty list, and in the callback to populate that list with results that are coming from the database. Once you got the data, simply notify the adapter about the changes, as explained in my answer from the following :

> [What miss, with connect Firestore and ListView for random results in sample?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50223779/what-miss-with-connect-firestore-and-listview-for-random-results-in-sample/50228240)