# i want to retrieve this reference in recycler view

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, arraylist, android-recyclerview

[image]

I tried many ways to get data from Direbase to RecyclerView but i was failed i implemented value event listener to reference and my database reference url is        `successofrderreference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("successorders");`
**and my value vent listener is:**

```
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    //Getting the data from snapshot
                    cartmodelclass cartmodelclass = postSnapshot.getValue(cartmodelclass.class);
                    md.add(cartmodelclass);


                    recyclerAdapforNormal = new RecyclerAdapforNormal(md);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapforNormal);
                }
            }
  @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull  DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

These are the classes which i used to retrive data from firebase references. I used value event listener and firebase query too but nothing works. So if anyone know how to fetch these data in one recycler view then please help me.

**cartModelclass**

```
public class cartmodelclass {
String image,description,reference,name,qty,status,orderdate,mode,delcharge;
int price;

public cartmodelclass(String image, String description, String reference, String name, String qty, String status, String orderdate, String mode, String delcharge, int price) {
    this.image = image;
    this.description = description;
    this.reference = reference;
    this.name = name;
    this.qty = qty;
    this.status = status;
    this.orderdate = orderdate;
    this.mode = mode;
    this.delcharge = delcharge;
    this.price = price;
}

public String getReference() {
    return reference;
}

public void setReference(String reference) {
    this.reference = reference;
}

public String getDelcharge() {
    return delcharge;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getOrderdate() {
    return orderdate;
}

public void setOrderdate(String orderdate) {
    this.orderdate = orderdate;
}

public String getMode() {
    return mode;
}

public void setMode(String mode) {
    this.mode = mode;
}

public void setDelcharge(String delcharge) {
    this.delcharge = delcharge;
}

public cartmodelclass() {
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getQty() {
    return qty;
}

public void setQty(String qty) {
    this.qty = qty;
}

public int getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(int price) {
    this.price = price;
}
```

}

**Recyclerview Adaptor**

```
public class RecyclerAdaptorformyordersectionNormal extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<cartmodelclass, RecyclerAdaptorformyordersectionNormal.ViewHolder> {


    public RecyclerAdaptorformyordersectionNormal(@NonNull  FirebaseRecyclerOptions<cartmodelclass> options) {
        super(options);
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerAdaptorformyordersectionNormal.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull  ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.normalorderslayout,parent,false);
        return new RecyclerAdaptorformyordersectionNormal.ViewHolder(v);

    }



    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull  RecyclerAdaptorformyordersectionNormal.ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull  cartmodelclass model) {
        int pric=model.getPrice();
        String qty=model.getQty();
        int q= Integer.parseInt(qty);

        int prisc= pric*q;
        String fip= String.valueOf(prisc);


        String finalstringprice= String.valueOf(model.getPrice());
        holder.cartname.setText(model.getName());
        holder.cartprice.setText(finalstringprice);
        holder.date.setText(model.getOrderdate());
        holder.status.setText(model.getStatus());
        holder.mode.setText(model.getMode());
        holder.cartqty.setText("Qty:- "+model.getQty());
        Picasso.get().load(model.getImage()).into(holder.cartimage);
        holder.delcharge.setText(model.getDelcharge());
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView cartname,cartprice,date,status,mode,cartqty,delcharge;
        ImageView cartimage,delte;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull  View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cartqty=itemView.findViewById(R.id.cartqty);
            delcharge=itemView.findViewById(R.id.delprice);
            cartname=itemView.findViewById(R.id.cartname);
            date=itemView.findViewById(R.id.orderdate);
            status=itemView.findViewById(R.id.status);
            mode=itemView.findViewById(R.id.modepayment);
            cartprice=itemView.findViewById(R.id.cartprice);
            cartimage=itemView.findViewById(R.id.cartimage);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the content of your `cartmodelclass` class.

Comment: @AlexMamo i have updated all classes which i used

Answer (score 0):

When using the following reference:

```
successofrderreference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
    .child(firebaseUser.getUid())
    .child("successorders");
```

And you attach a listener to it, it basically means that you are trying the read the data that exists right under this node.

When looping through the results, it means that you want to get all children one by one. When using the following line of code:

```
cartmodelclass cartmodelclass = postSnapshot.getValue(cartmodelclass.class);
```

It means that you are trying to convert each child that exists in your `DataSnapshot` object into an object of type `cartmodelclass`, which is not possible since, under the `successorders` node, there are no such objects. There are only some keys to other objects, and the keys in Fireabse are always Strings.

So, there are two ways in which you can solve his, you either add a call to `.child("2021-08-11 17:56:42")`:

```
successofrderreference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
    .child(firebaseUser.getUid())
    .child("successorders")
    .child("2021-08-11 17:56:42");
```

And get these lines out of the loop:

```
recyclerAdapforNormal = new RecyclerAdapforNormal(md);
recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapforNormal);
```

And remember not to set the adapter in a background thread, rather use my solution from the following post:

- [What miss, with connect Firestore and ListView for random results in sample?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50223779/what-miss-with-connect-firestore-and-listview-for-random-results-in-sample/50228240)

And inside the callback just notify the adapter about the changes. Or you change the database schema to look like this:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- $uid
        |
        --- successorders
              |
              --- 0
                  |
                  --- delcharge: "50"
                  |
                  --- date: "2021-08-11 17:56:42"
```

And create a query that looks like this:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference successReference = rootRef.child(uid).child("successorders");
Query query = successReference.orderByChild("date").equalTo("2021-08-11 17:56:42");
```

At a first glance, the rest of the code can remain unchanged.

Comment: But i want to show the whole reference data which is in successorders reference not particular, the whole data like in 2021-08-11 17:56:42, same this type of next reference data in recycler view

Comment: That was just an example. I have added only two properties for simplicity. You should use all the properties in the class.